# Show that $E(Y^4) \geq (E[Y^2])^{2}$ using Jensen's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, inequality

I'm a bit stuck
I need to show that $E[Y^{4}] \geq (E[Y^2])^2$ where $Y$ has finite second moment using Jensen's Inequality.

I know that $Y^{4}$ has finite second moment so using jensen's inequality I have:

$E[Y^4] \geq (E[Y])^4 =E([Y])^{2} \cdot E([Y])^{2}$

But then I get stuck since I need $(E[Y^2])^2$ but I have things in terms of $E[Y]$. Thanks for the help.

Or is this right:
$E[Y^4]=E[(Y^2)^2)] \geq (E(Y^2))^2$ since $y^2$ is convex? Thanks

Comment: The last sentence is on spot. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031062/proof-of-nonnegativity-of-kl-divergence-using-jensens-inequality/2031944#2031944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see that $E(X^2)\geq (E(X))^2$ by Jensen's inequality? Let $X=Y^2$.

Comment: Hi @user658409 I just did this and added to my solution. Did I do it right? I realized I wasn't thinking.

Comment: Another example of having composite in Jensen's inequality is the answer in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031062/proof-of-nonnegativity-of-kl-divergence-using-jensens-inequality/2031944. The convexity of internal function is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you are confused, let me include a self-contained proof that does not involve Jensen's inequality, to make it crystal clear why this is true.
Consider the quantity which is obviously non-negative:
$$
\mathbb E\bigl(Y^2-\mathbb E(Y^2)\bigr)^2\geq 0.
$$
Now expand the square and collect like terms to learn that
$$
\mathbb E\bigl(Y^2-\mathbb E(Y^2)\bigr)^2=\mathbb E(Y^4)-\bigl(\mathbb E(Y^2)\bigr)^2.
$$
Therefore $\mathbb E(Y^4)\geq \bigl(\mathbb E(Y^2)\bigr)^2.$